# How do I remove the 7th and 8th to last characters in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to remove the the 7th and 8th to last characters in a string.

```
$string = "Tucson AZ 85718";
```

I am trying to remove the state abbreviation.  I have a bunch of these strings for different zip codes, so I can't just replace "AZ" with ''.

Comment: For this string you can use $string = preg_replace ( '%(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+?)%', '$1 $3', $string ). For more exact pattern more examples are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = substr($string, 0, -8) . substr($string, -5);
```

Demo:

```
php> $string = "Tucson AZ 85718";
php> echo substr($string, 0, -8) . substr($string, -5);
Tucson 85718
```

A regex would also do the job. This one would remove any 2-uppercase-character string and the space after it:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b[A-Z]{2}\b /', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = substr_replace($string, "", -8, 2);
```

Comment: Would it remove characters at the 7th and 8th position from the last?

Comment: Assuming your data is all well formed (and identical to your sample), this is by far the neatest solution

Comment: Hah, actually should be `substr_replace($string, "", -9, 3)`, no?

Answer (score 0):

not an php regexp expert, but it seems that

```
$string=preg_replace(" {w{1}} ", " ", $string);
```

would do the job for you. Should work with variable length city name.:wq

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not American and don't know American postal addresses too well!

I would definitely do this with `preg_replace` or `preg_match_all`:

```
$string   = "Tucson AZ 85718"; 

// Don't be mislead by the second [A-Z], this means all uppercase characters
$pattern  = '/^(.+ )([A-Z]{2} )(\d+)$/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This'll give you an array that looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Tucson AZ 85718"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Tucson "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "AZ "
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "85718"
  }
}
```

...where the 2nd, 3rd and 4th indexes will be the City, State code and Zip code respectively.

Alternatively, you could just strip the prefix with `preg_replace`:

```
$string   = "Tucson AZ 85718"; 
$pattern  = '/^(.+ )([A-Z]{2} )(\d+)$/';
$normalised = preg_replace($pattern, '$1$3', $string);
```

...which will give you "Tucson 85718", where the `$1 and $3` in the second argument to `preg_replace` relate to the first and third blocks in parenthesis in the pattern (`(.* )` and `(\d{5})` respectively).

Assumptions:

- States codes are all caps
- Zip codes are all 5 digits